# Kubernetes: Cannot deploy flask web app with apache and https

Tags: apache, docker, kubernetes

I have a local Kubernetes cluster on a single machine, and I successfully deployed a flask web app using apache server, so there shouldn't be any problem with the cluster setup. However, I need to upgrade the website to https, so I used `letsencrypt` to generate ssl certificates and volume mapped them into the container. I also successfully deployed the app without docker, i.e. directly start the apache server using `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND`. I can visit my website at `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.edu` without problem.

However, when I started putting everything into Docker and Kubernetes, and visited `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.edu:30001`, the browser gave me this error:

```
This site can’t be reached

XXX.XXX.XXX.edu took too long to respond
```

Here is how I deployed:

I first started the service `kubectl create -f web-service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    name: web
    role: "ssl-proxy"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30001
      name: "https"
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: "TCP"
    - nodePort: 30000
      name: "http"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: "TCP"
  selector:
    name: web
    role: "ssl-proxy"
```

Then I started the pod `kubectl create -f web-controller.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: XXX/web_app
        command: ['/bin/sh', '-c']
        args: ['sudo a2enmod ssl && service apache2 restart && sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND && python fake.py']
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          name: http-server
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/letsencrypt/live/host
            name: test-volume
            readOnly: false
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /etc/letsencrypt/archive/XXX.XXX.XXX.edu
          name: test-volume
```

The log of the pod looks like:

```
root@XXX:~# kubectl logs web-controller-ontne
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
Module setenvif already enabled
Considering dependency mime for ssl:
Module mime already enabled
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
Module socache_shmcb already enabled
Module ssl already enabled
 * Restarting web server apache2
[Mon Jun 27 14:34:48.753153 2016] [so:warn] [pid 30:tid 140046645868416] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
   ...done.
[Mon Jun 27 14:34:49.820047 2016] [so:warn] [pid 119:tid 139909591328640] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd (pid 33) already running
root@XXX:~#
```

The pod is running, but I got the following apache error log:

```
[Mon Jun 27 17:13:50.912683 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 33:tid 140513871427456] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 0.0.0.0i:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I think the problem is that, I am using NodePort and exposing port 30001, so I have to visit `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.edu:30001` which does not match `XXX.XXX.XXX.edu` (just the domain name without the arbitrary port number 30001).

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` in the docker container:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:30001>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/my_app

    LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_ssl.so
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host/cert1.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host/privkey1.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host/chain1.pem

    WSGIDaemonProcess python-app user=www-data group=www-data threads=15 maximum-requests=10000 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-p
ackages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/my_app/apache/apache.wsgi
    WSGIProcessGroup python-app

    CustomLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /usr/local/my_app/apache/logs/access.log.%Y%m%d-%H%M%S 5M" combined
    ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /usr/local/my_app/apache/logs/error.log.%Y%m%d-%H%M%S 5M"
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory /usr/local/my_app>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

How to modify it so that apache serves https requests at port 30001 rather than 443? Thank you very much!

Comment: Query the logs on the web-controller and add them to the post please

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: Just added.

Comment: The strange line is `Restarting web server apache2` : It should not restart and seems to be failing at that.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: I just added a fake server which is essentially an infinite loop, so the pod is running rather than completed. Now I can get some error log produced by apache, which I add to the post above. Could you take a look at it and help me? Thanks!

Comment: Notify me when the log is there and I will take a look

Comment: To avoid that RSA warning from producing side effects: Start with http only and see if that is stable. If so: Then you have the root cause :)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: I just posted the Kubernetes log for the pod, the apache pod retrieved inside the running container, and the apache config file. Thanks!

Comment: Did you already try the run without the https enabled?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: I am trying, but ```watch "kubectl get pod"``` says the pod is terminating for almost 2 hours. I shouldn't start a new pod without the current one terminated.```docker stop f75c64f1ce52``` goes into an infinite loop :(

Comment: @ NorbertvanNobelen : Is there any way to detect or quickly kill the pod? Thanks!

Comment: You can try to kill the process using the normal kill command, Then you can be more force full (kill -KILL if needed)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: after rebooting the server, restarting everything from scratch, and countless trials and errors, I figured out the solution myself. Still, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. 2 causes: (1) There is an environment variable specific to my web app that I forgot to set in `apache.wsgi`; (2) There are several small errors in the original apache configuration file. I post the working `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` here:

```
ServerName 0.0.0.0

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/my_app

    LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_ssl.so
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host/cert1.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host/privkey1.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host/chain1.pem

    WSGIDaemonProcess python-app user=www-data group=www-data threads=15 maximum-requests=10000 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/my_app/apache/apache.wsgi
    WSGIProcessGroup python-app

    CustomLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /usr/local/my_app/apache/logs/access.log.%Y%m%d-%H%M%S 5M" combined
    ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /usr/local/my_app/apache/logs/error.log.%Y%m%d-%H%M%S 5M"
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory /usr/local/my_app>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Start the pod with commands `sudo a2enmod ssl && sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND`, and `containerPort` should be 443. The Kubernetes script for the service is as simple as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    name: web
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30001
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: web
```

Now I can visit my web site at `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:30001`.

Special thanks to the owner of [this github repo](https://github.com/muneeb-ali/apache-flask) and NorbertvanNobelen. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just run into this issue this morning.

I expose the employment using `--type=NodePort`
I can access it from either

```
http://<pod ip>:<target port> 
http://<cluster IP>: <port>
```

But I can not access it from

```
  http://<Node IP>:< NodePort>
```

The Chrome say: `.... took too long to respond`

I check pod's status. It is ready and running

Later I fixed it by:
delete the deployment and service.

1. create deployment
2. watch the pod till its status became 'running'
3. expose this deployment using  `--type=NodePort`

I find now the pod is running on another node.
I check

```
 http://<new Node IP>:< new NodePort>
```

It works

I do not know what is the reason.
Just guess:

1. make sure the pod is created and in running status before expose
   the deployment
2. maybe it is related with the cluster IP allocated by k8s
3. maybe there is something wrong with the node machine it ever was running on.